# Display single image multiple times in a table using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make a game in which there is an 8x8 table and a coin displays on them(more than at 10 positions at a time) for 3000milliseconds on different position simultaneously. The coin display should start at a click of "Start" button and it continues for 1minute. My problem is that I am not able to make a random function which generates images randomly on different positions.it is giving some error of appendchild undefined.I want my image to display randomly on different positions),Here what I've tried so far.I've just started learning JS so please don't judge my code & i'm posting this again because i didn't get any response in my previous post.
I had "display:none;" all the coins and i want a random function at multiple positions on which the coins displays block. 
PS:I can't use any Jquery and remove the mistakes done previously

```js
function tableCreate(){
    var body = document.body;
    var tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width  = '730px';
    tbl.style.height = '650px';
    tbl.style.border = '4px solid grey';
 tbl.style.display = 'inline-block';

    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
   var td = tr.insertCell();
      var div = document.createElement('div');
            td.appendChild(div);
      div.innerHTML = '<img src="coin.png" alt="coin.png" class="coin_img" id="coin_image">';
            td.style.border = '1px solid black';
   td.style.width = '85px';
   td.style.height = '75px';
   td.id = 'r' + i + 'c' + j;
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl);
 
}
function onTimer() {
    var seconds = 60;
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        seconds--;
        counter.innerHTML = "<h1>Time Left:-"+"0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds)+"</h1>";
        if( seconds > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {
            alert("Game over");
        }
    }
    tick();
  setInterval(function(){
   var tbl = document.createElement('table');
   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
   var tr = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")[randomNumber];
   var td = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td")[randomNumber];
   var img = tbl.getElementById("coin_image");
   td[randomNumber].appendChild(img);
   img.style.display = "block";
 }, 3000);
}

function onRestart()
{
 location.reload();
}
```

```css
.button_class
{
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 400px;
}
.btn
{
 width: 140px;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 20px;
   font-size: 16px;
 background-color: 
}
.coin_img
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 display: none;
}
.counter_div
{
 margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="tableCreate()">
 <div class="button_class">
    <button type="button" name="start_button" class="start_button btn" id="st_button" onclick="onTimer()">Start</button>
   <button type="button" name="restart_button"  class="restart_button btn" id="rs_button" onclick="onRestart()">Restart</button>
   <div class="counter_div" id="counter">
      <h1>Total Time:-1:00</h1>
    </div>
 </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new table and then you're trying to find elements inside your empty table? (Inside your set interval).

Answer (score 0):

I think I could tweak your code:

```js
function tableCreate(){
    var body = document.body;
    var tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.id = 'myTable';
    tbl.style.width  = '730px';
    tbl.style.height = '650px';
    tbl.style.border = '4px solid grey';
   tbl.style.display = 'inline-block';

    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
   var td = tr.insertCell();
      var div = document.createElement('div');
            td.appendChild(div);
      div.innerHTML = '<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/awicons/vista-artistic/128/coin-icon.png" alt="coin.png" class="coin_img" id="coin_image">';
            td.style.border = '1px solid black';
   td.style.width = '85px';
   td.style.height = '75px';
   td.id = 'r' + i + 'c' + j;
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl);
 
}
function onTimer() {
    var seconds = 60;
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        seconds--;
        counter.innerHTML = "<h1>Time Left:-"+"0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds)+"</h1>";
        if( seconds > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {
            alert("Game over");
        }
    }
    tick();
  setInterval(function(){
   var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable');
   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
   var tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr"))[randomNumber];
   var td = Array.prototype.slice.call(tr.getElementsByTagName("td"))[randomNumber];
   var img = document.getElementById("coin_image");
   td.appendChild(img);
   img.style.display = "block";
 }, 3000);
}

function onRestart()
{
 location.reload();
}
```

```css
.button_class
{
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 400px;
}
.btn
{
 width: 140px;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 20px;
   font-size: 16px;
 background-color: 
}
.coin_img
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 display: none;
}
.counter_div
{
 margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="tableCreate()">
 <div class="button_class">
    <button type="button" name="start_button" class="start_button btn" id="st_button" onclick="onTimer()">Start</button>
   <button type="button" name="restart_button"  class="restart_button btn" id="rs_button" onclick="onRestart()">Restart</button>
   <div class="counter_div" id="counter">
      <h1>Total Time:-1:00</h1>
    </div>
 </div> 
</body>
```

Your inaccuracies:

- add an id to the table when you initially create it in function `tableCreate()` like `tbl.id ='myTable';`
- variable `tbl` in `onTimer()` function shoudn't contain a new table but
  rather the existing one like `var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable');`
- functions like `getElementsByTagName("tr")` return HTMLCollections,
  not arrays. To convert it into array use
  `Array.prototype.slice.call(tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr"))`
- If I am not mistaken, you can call `getElementById` only on
  `document`, so it should be `var img = document.getElementById("coin_image");`, not `var img =tbl.getElementById("coin_image");`
- `td` variable in `onTimer`'s interval already contains the td
  element, no need to add an index. So, it should be
  `td.appendChild(img);`
- In order to avoid placing all the coins in the same row, change `var
  td = Array.prototype.slice.call(tbl.getElementsByTagName("td"))[randomNumber];`
  to `var td = Array.prototype.slice.call(tr.getElementsByTagName("td"))[randomNumber];`

It makes your code work, but there are some other, lets say, logical problems because the coins do not disappear from the cells. Also they only appear on cells with coordinates like (0,0) (2,2) (4,4) etc. because you generate the random number only once and then use it for both - row and column. I don't know maybe it is what you want. If not, work on it too.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly what you are looking for but it may works using same id multiple times is not a good choice

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function tableCreate(){
    var body = document.body;
    var tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width  = '730px';
    tbl.style.height = '650px';
    tbl.style.border = '4px solid grey';
    tbl.style.display = 'inline-block';

for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
        var td = tr.insertCell();
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        td.appendChild(div);
        div.innerHTML = '<img src="coin.png" alt="coin.png" class="coin_img" id="coin_image'+i+'">';
        td.style.border = '1px solid black';
        td.style.width = '85px';
        td.style.height = '75px';
        td.id = 'r' + i + 'c' + j;
    }
}
body.appendChild(tbl);  
}
function onTimer() {
    var seconds = 60;
    function tick() {
       var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
       seconds--;
       counter.innerHTML = "<h1>Time Left:-"+"0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds)+"</h1>";
    if( seconds > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    } else {
        alert("Game over");
    }
}
tick();
    setInterval(function(){
        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        //var tr = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")[randomNumber];
        //var td = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td")[randomNumber];
        var img = document.getElementById("coin_image"+randomNumber+"");
        //td[randomNumber].appendChild(img);
        img.style.display = "block";
}, 3000);
}
function onRestart()
{
location.reload();
}
```